# How to check if a pipeline is triggered from a pull request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins pipeline to build Pull Requests branches using the GitHub Organization plugin.

I can build them fine, but I want to avoid some steps (such as publishing the artifacts). Checking git's current branch gives me the PR's target since the PR branch is being merged into the target before the build is attempted.

How can I check if the build is being initiated from a PR vs than a regular branch build?

Comment: PRs have different envs from regular branches. Plus you can check the current directory. It has the name PR in it if it's PR

Comment: So I assume running `sh "set"` might give you some indicators..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

At least on Jenkins 2.16 `env.BRANCH_NAME` gives the source branch not the target branch. You could do something like:

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
  sh "./publish.sh"
}
```

Other env vars that could be useful are the `CHANGE_*` variables. E.g.,

```
CHANGE_AUTHOR='me'
CHANGE_ID='6'
CHANGE_TARGET='master'
CHANGE_TITLE='Update README.md'
CHANGE_URL='https://github.com/test-org/test-repo/pull/6'
```

For documentation on these and more: https://ci.eclipse.org/webtools/env-vars.html/

Comment: I ended up doing a check if the branch name was PR-\d+

Comment: You should have post that @ESG

Comment: docs for CHANGE_* vars:
https://hudson.eclipse.org/webtools/env-vars.html/ and
"The full list of environment variables accessible from within Jenkins Pipeline is documented at ${YOUR_JENKINS_URL}/pipeline-syntax/globals#env" per
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

Comment: The link you provided (https://hudson.eclipse.org/webtools/env-vars.html/) requires an account.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, I've updated it to https://ci.eclipse.org/webtools/env-vars.html

Answer (score 30):

The env variable `CHANGE_ID` only exists when the build is triggered from a Pull Request check.

> For a multibranch project corresponding to some kind of change request, this will be set to the change ID, such as a pull request number, if supported; else unset.

Comment: Doc for above - https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/

Answer (score 10):

To specifically detect GitHub pull requests, this can be used:

```
  script {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
      sh 'make'
    } else if (env.BRANCH_NAME.startsWith('PR')) {
      // do actions for pull request
    } else {
      // some other branch
    } 
  }
```

Of course, if you expect to have branches starting with PR on your main repository this wouldn't be reliable. The nice thing about it is that `script` can be used also in `post` not just `stages`, which is useful since `when` is not allowed in `post`. If you don't care about that it's worth looking into the `when` directive. There is some documentation from [Cloudbees](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/use/reference/pipeline/) and [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to solve this scenario, you can SIMPLY turn off your "Pull requests" event in the Webhooks section in your Github organization.

Steps:

1. Go to your repository settings in GitHub.
2. Click on Webhooks.
3. Select the webhook used for Jenkins integration.
4. Under "Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?", select "Let me select individual events."
5. Choose only the events you are interested in, such as "Pushes," and avoid selecting "Pull requests."
6. Save your changes.